# Why can't we quantify over propositional functions in the ZFC set theory?

Tags: logic, set-theory

What's the difference between saying

> if $P(y)$ is some propositional function, then we can create an axiom 
>   ${\forall}z{\exists}x:(y{\in}x{\iff}y{\in}z{\land}P(y)$

and saying

> ${\forall}P(y)({\forall}z{\exists}x:(y{\in}x{\iff}y{\in}z{\land}P(y))$

?

Comment: ZFC is supposed to be a first order theory, and that is simply not allowed in one.

Comment: Are you assuming $P$ is a propositional function, or that $P(y)$ is a propositional function?  If $P(y)$ is a propositional function, then it is not a boolean, and $z \land P(y)$ isn't meaningful, you would need to write something like $z \land P(y)(a)$.  On the other hand, if $P$ is a propositional function, then $z \land P(y)$ has meaning.

Answer (score 1):

[Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html) is a first-order theory and in first-order logic we cannot quantify over *predicate* letters.

This is the reason why we have e.g. the **Separation Axiom schema**:

> $∀z∃x∀y \ [y∈x \leftrightarrow y∈z \land \varphi(y)]$, for very wff $\varphi(y)$.

Comment: I accept that we cannot quantify over predicate letters (in fol), and have seen it stated numerous times, but what happens if you try? I naïvely attempted to do this in [my question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1726068/244596) by arithmetizing them

Comment: @Szmagpie - quantifying **only** on *individual* variables in first-order logic is a "rule of the game". What happens it you do not follow the rules ? You are making a mistake. What happens if in your elementary arithmetic classroom you write on the blackbord that $1+1=3$ ?

Comment: As explained by previous answers, s-o logic is a absolutely legitimate field of research and has many interesting aspects. But f-o logic is "more clean and simple". In f-o logic we cannot quantify over *predicate* letters (**not** formulae): the usual way to (partially) circumvent the issue is to use *axiom schematas. For example, instead of writing the induction axiom as follows (see original Peano's 1889 formulation) : $\forall K \subseteq \mathbb N (0 \in K \land \ldots \to \mathbb N \subseteq K)$ we have to write the schema: $\varphi(0) \land \dots \to \forall n \varphi(n)$.

Comment: What is the **big** difference? while there are *uncountable* many subsets of $\mathbb N$, due to the fact that a f-o formula $\varphi$ is a *finite* string of symbols, we have only *countable* many formulae; thus, only countable many possible instances of the schema.