# Why can't we quantify over propositional functions/open formulas in first order languages?

Tags: logic

The rule of formation concerning quantifiers in first order languages is

> If $x$ is a variable and $P$ is a WFF, then ${\forall}x(P)$ is a WFF.

Apparently we can't quantify over propositional functions (i.e. open formulas) in first order languages. Since the above is the rule of formation concernig quantifying over things, it seems like it's supposed to prohibit open formulas from being quantified over. How exactly? How aren't open formulas variables themselves?

Or does the prohibition of quantifying over open formulas stem from another source?

Comment: In what sense would you expect an open formula to be a variable? A variable is a variable, and a formula is a formula. On a purely syntactic level, a variable is in the alphabet, whereas a formula is in the language.

Comment: Quantifying over *relations* (a restricted type of open formula) brings us by definition to second-order logic. Nothing wrong with second-order logic, but it does not have a satisfactory notion of proof.

Comment: I second neth's confusion: why do you think open formulas are variables?

Answer (score 0):

First-order logic is usually formulated without any propositional variables to quantify over.

This is not a big loss, because if you have a reasoning that involves propositional variables (and quantifying over them), you can still simulate it in first-order logic by introducing a new unary predicate $p$ and axioms $\exists x.p(x)$ and $\exists x.\neg p(x)$.

Then instead of
$$\forall X.\exists Y. \cdots X \cdots Y \cdots $$
you would simply write
$$\forall x.\exists y. \cdots p(x) \cdots p(y) \cdots $$

---

If you want to quantify over propositional *functions*, you could in principle quantify over the value of each line in the function's truth table. That's not going to be pretty, but it'll work.

Comment: It appears the OP wants to do $\forall p$ instead of $\forall $x$, presumable to have e.g. only a single Axiom of Separation instead f the Axiom Schema of Separation ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: You're probably right, especially in light of [the OP's earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739723/why-cant-we-quantify-over-propositional-functions-in-the-zfc-set-theory).